# Trouble producing a query that groups a selection of groups

Tags: oracle, group-by, reporting

In terms of context, I believe that all that is needed is to know that I have a table, t_sale, that logs sales made. It logs a few things, such as day and location of sale in the shop, but what is important for this is that sale_time and sale_value (arbitrary categories for the sale price, LOW, MED, and HIGH) are logged.

The problem I am having is that I need to produce a report that breaks down sales in each hour, for each value category. I have successfully done both of these things individually with. For getting the number of sales by hour:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(hour FROM sale_time) AS Hour, COUNT(sale_time) AS Sales
FROM t_sale
GROUP BY EXTRACT(hour FROM sale_time)
ORDER BY Sales DESC;
```

which results in this (shop is open 0900 to 1700):

```
*HOUR*  *SALES*
13      99
16      99
9       94
10      91
11      89
15      87
12      82
14      79
```

And producing a report for sales by value, I used this query to get the data and columns I needed:

```
SELECT sale_value AS "Sale Value", COUNT(sale_value) AS "Total Sales"
FROM t_sale
GROUP BY sale_value
HAVING sale_value IN ('HIGH', 'MED', 'LOW');
```

which results in this:

```
*VALUE* *SALES*
HIGH    241
LOW     244
MED     235
```

What I am imaging is being requested is something that, in place of sales for the values example, further breaks it down by each hour. Something like:

```
*VALUE*    *HOUR*    *SALES*
HIGH       09        22
           10        14
           11        31
           etc...    etc...

MED        09        52
           10        16
           11        19
           etc...    etc...

LOW        09        63
           10        33
           11        28
           etc...    etc...
```

I've used dbForge Studio 2020 for Oracle for the report on the values due to no end of issues with Oracle Forms and Reports. I'm confident I can make the report if I knew what query to use to generate the data. However I am completely at a loss as to what functions to use.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this work?

```
SELECT 
  sale_value AS "Sale Value", 
  EXTRACT(hour FROM sale_time) AS Hour,
  COUNT(sale_value) AS "Total Sales"
FROM t_sale
GROUP BY sale_value, EXTRACT(hour FROM sale_time)
HAVING sale_value IN ('HIGH', 'MED', 'LOW');
```

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I was making such a stupid mistake! That's what you get for trying to Oracle/SQL at 0300.

Comment: Haha.. Haven't we all been there!